# SKScene lingering in background after present new scene

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

In my app, I have 3 different subclasses of SKScene for my menu, game, and game over screens. When the player hits an obstacle during the game, I present a new game over scene using:

```
EndGame *endGame = [[EndGame alloc] initWithSize:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size];
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *)self.view;
[spriteView presentScene:endGame];
```

However, my gameScene is still running in the background (I can tell by printing a message in the update method). How can I make sure to deallocate the instance of the gameScene when I present the game over scene?

Currently, when I move between scenes my memory usage slowly increments.

Comment: are you retaining the scene somewhere as a strong property?

Comment: I have no idea what that means, so probably not.

Comment: Oh, no I never did that.

Comment: based on what you posted it should work.. there might be something else you're doing.  why not try it on a stripped down project and see if you get the same result?

Comment: After trying a stripped down project, I found the problem. The update method did stop when I moved from the view. When I said earlier that I was using the update method, when I was actually using a custom timer to run my physics. I assumed this timer would automatically be invalidated when I moved from the view, but for some reason it kept running in the background. All I had to do was invalidate the timer before moving from the view. Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you know why the timer wasn't automatically terminated? If the timer was still running after I moved from the view, something tells me that the view was still using memory

Answer (score 0):

Although you find the solution to your answer, I had something similar.

I have a navigationController which shows a MainViewController from which you can go to the GameViewController (with SKScene). After a 'game over' I would pop back to the MainViewController, however, my scene (in GameViewController) was still running in the background. I checked by printing the TimeInterval in the update() function.

What I ended up doing was, in my viewDidDisappear, i did a

```
skView.presentScene(nil)
```

This removed the scene in my case and freed up any memory it was using.